# Split method in a Do loop to separate string values in an array by whitespace

Tags: ruby, methods

I have an array:
`array = ["John Smith", "Bill Taylor", Troy Tate"]`

I am trying to use the `split` method to print either the first name or last name only from each name in the array.  I am using the following, but the `array.split(" ")` is obviously only splitting the strings into two at the whitespace.

How can I use the '.string' method to only print either the first or last name.  Or first character for that matter?

```
array = ["John Smith", "Bill Taylor", Troy Tate"]

array.each do |array|
  puts array.split(" ")
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything like this?

```
array.each { |name| puts name.split.sample }
```

Comment: To get a random element from the array [name, surname]